# Should nested relationships be reflected in URLs for JSON API?

Tags: json-api

I'm trying to follow [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/). I need to expose CRUD access to a nested resource: product reviews.

Prior to using JSON API, I'd expect a REST interface like this:

```
GET    /products/:product_id/reviews     - list reviews for a product
POST   /products/:product_id/reviews     - add a review for a product
PATCH  /products/:product_id/reviews/:id - update a review for a product
DELETE /products/:product_id/reviews/:id - delete a review for a product
```

I see some mention of a nested structure like this [in the spec](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#urls-relationships):

> For example, the URL for a photo’s comments will be:
>
> `/photos/1/comments`

But I'm not sure whether this structure is intended for all actions.

On the one hand, `POST /products/:product_id/reviews` for creation seems redundant if I'm going to specify the product in the POST body, under the review data's `relationships`.

On the other hand, if it's useful to specify a product id when deleting a review (maybe it isn't), `DELETE /products/:product_id/reviews/:id` seems like the only sane way to do it; [people argue about whether a request body is even allowed for DELETE requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request).

I could nest for some requests and not others:

```
GET    /products/:product_id/reviews  - list reviews for a product
POST   /products/:product_id/reviews  - add a review for a product
PATCH  /reviews/:id                   - update a review
DELETE /reviews/:id                   - delete a review
```

But that seems weirdly inconsistent.

I could never nest:

```
GET    /reviews     - list reviews for the product specified in params
POST   /reviews     - add a review for the product specified in params
PATCH  /reviews/:id - update a review
DELETE /reviews/:id - delete a review
```

But that seems awkward, and doesn't seem to match the first quote I made from the docs.

**Should nested resource relationships be reflected in the URL when using JSON API?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I really like your question, since I have been having the same thoughts. I'm puzzled that no one has left an answer yet.

I have been using JSON API a little over a year on a production system and I would like to give my two cents.

At first when I started the project that was going to use JSON API, I was in doubt of nested vs non-nested resources. I then ran into issues with nested resources that would have been avoided with non-nested resources.

To take the same paths as in your example, consider the `GET /products/:product_id/reviews` endpoint.
When this is made it make very much sense to nest a review under a product because we are initially showing reviews in context of a product. Everything is good.

We then later want to build a page in the frontend that shows a user and all the reviews that user has authored.
Although we already have an endpoint for getting reviews, we will have to build a new one, e.g. `GET /users/:id/reviews`.

If we hade just put the first endpoint on `GET /reviews` with a filter of `?filter[product_id]=:id`, we could just add a new filter to that endpoint, which makes much sense IMO.

I do use nested resources, but only for singleton resources like `GET /users/:id/email_settings` and a few other special cases where it makes sense.

In my experience, it makes it easier in the future if each resource is thought of as independent from other resources. There exists resources and relationships between resources. No resource "owns" another resource in the context of the API (in context of business-logic it's another story).

I have worked with this strategy and it still surprises me how well it works when adding new functionality to existing endpoints and when adding new endpoints.

Comment: I also wanted to add that this fits well into the idea that there should be exactly 1 canonical URI for any particular resource. With nested resources, you might end up with many locations for the same resource, e.g. `/products/1/review/1` and `/reviews/1`.

An important distinction w.r.t. JSON API is that [_relationship_ resources](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-relationships) do not seem violate this idea. They are the canonical location for the _relationship_ between two things, e.g. `/products/1/relationships/reviews/1` represents the association  between these resources.

Comment: Thanks Lasse and @iamvery for sharing your insights! This is the approach I ended up using.

Comment: JSONAPI want you to be able to uniquely identify a resource so If the canonical URL is "nested" like `/prod/1/rev/2` then the design is implying that `rev` only exists within `prod` and its `id` is composite. The spec allows this but building the id gets tricky. Otherwise, if canonical URL is `/rev/2` then no problem. Here `/prod/1/rev/2` is just an endpoint to describe the related items and could be literally described any way you want. The spec does not dictate how to build the URLs.

Answer (score 4):

If you coming from CQRS camp, you will understand why design Restful API sometimes awkward. It is awkward because naturally Query actions (GET) and Mutation actions (POST, PATCH, DELETE) should talk in two different languages. 
Query actions naturally relationship-oriented and data rich; while Mutation actions not. So it feel easy to use nested URL to traversal between relationship entities. 
But Mutation you should provide just enough information for tasks. Sometimes it is redundant like your Post example. Sometimes missing like your DELETE example. Sometimes you have a task involve many resources; you don't know where to put in.

You should check Facebook Graph API or Azure Graph API, they met same problems and have some good solutions. It's important that you should follow consistent design.
Some rules are:

- DELETE, UPDATE always to direct resource.
- POST use with nested resource if you want create both object and main relationship. Secondary relationships should put in BODY. If you have two equal relationships, consider have both nested APIs.
- Use POST against fake resource to for tasks involve with many resources.

  > POST /transferfund
- Use POST against fake relationship for tasks could not fit with any HTTP verbs. For example, you want have body for delete action, use

  > POST /resource/id/deleteItForMe
  >   { reason: "I hate it"}